# quartz scheduler sample program giving error

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to run the sample helloworld program for quartz scheduling given on roseindi.net
http://www.roseindia.net/quartz/quartz-scheduler-tutorial.shtml

I have both the classes given there exactly similar setup in my java projecy with quartz version 1.6 - all.jar in the project library.
When I try to run the application I get the following Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/UserTransaction
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.instantiate(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1104)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.getScheduler(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1355)
    at oiaoerpdataconnector.HelloSchedule.HelloScheduleRun(HelloSchedule.java:25)
    at oiaoerpdataconnector.HelloSchedule.main(HelloSchedule.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.transaction.UserTransaction
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 4 more
Java Result: 1
```

What am I missing here?
Thanks,
Priyank

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> What am I missing here?

[`jta.jar`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/transaction/jta/1.1/jta-1.1.jar)

Comment: It puzzles me that most Quartz demos and examples I come across omit this.  Thank you.