# Using Quartz Scheduler For Jobs

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, quartz-scheduler

Hello I just started using Quartz Scheduler, I followed the instructions here:
https://dzone.com/articles/quartz-scheduler-configuration-for-web-application

First of all I added the dependencies to my pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
    <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
    <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

However when I start tomcat my app fails to load and I get this error in my logs:

> Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of
>   class [org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener]
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/UserTransaction at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)  at
>   java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)   at
>   java.beans.Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods(Introspector.java:1336)
>     at
>   java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1197)
>     at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:426)   at
>   java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:173)    at
>   org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.setBeanProps(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1393)
>     at
>   org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.instantiate(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1057)
>     at
>   org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.getScheduler(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1519)
>     at
>   org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener.contextInitialized(QuartzInitializerListener.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4643)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5105)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:671)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493) Caused
>   by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   javax.transaction.UserTransaction     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1275)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1104)
>     ... 42 more
>
> Dec 21, 2017 9:40:08 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
>   startInternal SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full
>   details will be found in the appropriate container log file Dec 21,
>   2017 9:40:08 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
>   SEVERE: Context [/enshika] startup failed due to previous errors Dec
>   21, 2017 9:40:08 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO:
>   Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"] Dec 21, 2017 9:40:08 AM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"] Dec 21, 2017 9:40:08 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start INFO: Server startup in
>   16141 ms

I added this to my web.xml file as instructed:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

I created a quartz.properties file and a quartz-jobs.xml file and placed them in my src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [quartz scheduler sample program giving error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608256/quartz-scheduler-sample-program-giving-error)

Comment: Thank you very much I actually googled but couldn't find a similar problem, will try that out and see :)

Comment: Which is the java version ? and Tomcat version ? I think you got the problem with versions here.